# dont allow user to select existing date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

So the user selects holidays (start and end dates) from two calendars, the dates from start to end are then stored in the DB in separate records per date.

(thanks to help from a previous question this all works fine)

Now, I want some sort of error message which doesnt allow the button to be clicked if the dates the user are selecting already exist in the DB.

Im unsure if this is done from the view, or controller?

View:

```
<form action ="ListHolidays" id="listHolidays" method="post">
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Holiday</legend>

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonId, "Person")
        </div>

        <div>     
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PersonId,
                                new SelectList(ViewBag.Id, "Value", "Text"),
                                "---Select---"
                                )   
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonId)            
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HolidayDate)
        </div>

        <div>

            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HolidayDate)

            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.endDate)
    <script>

//        Date.format = 'dd/m/yyy';
        $("#HolidayDate").addClass('date-pick');
        $("#endDate").addClass('date-pick');
            //$('.date-pick').datePicker//({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'}).val();

//        clickInput: true

        $(function () {
        //3 methods below dont allow user to select weekends
            $('.date-pick').datePicker(
               {
                   createButton: false,
                   renderCallback: function ($td, thisDate, month, year) 
                   {
                       if (thisDate.isWeekend()) 
                       {
                           $td.addClass('weekend');
                           $td.addClass('disabled');
                       }
                   }
               }
        )

        .bind('click',
            function () 
            {
                $(this).dpDisplay();
                this.blur();
                return false;
            }
        )

        .bind('dateSelected',
            function (e, selectedDate, $td) 
            {
                console.log('You selected ' + selectedDate);
            }
        );

//        HolidayDate is start date
            $('#HolidayDate').bind('dpClosed',
                    function (e, selectedDates) 
                    {
                        var d = selectedDates[0];
                        if (d) 
                        {
                            d = new Date(d);
                            $('#endDate').dpSetStartDate(d.addDays(1).asString());
                        }
                    }
            );

            //end date is end date
            $('#endDate').bind('dpClosed',
                    function (e, selectedDates) 
                    {
                        var d = selectedDates[0];
                        if (d) 
                        {
                            d = new Date(d);
                            $('#HolidayDate').dpSetEndDate(d.addDays(-1).asString());
                        }
                    }
                );
        });



    </script>

     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HolidayDate)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
        </p>
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult listHolidays(Holiday holiday, int? PersonId, string HolidayDate, string endDate)
    {

            DateTime startDates = Convert.ToDateTime(HolidayDate),
                     endDates = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate);

            while (startDates <= endDates)
            {
                if (startDates.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && startDates.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    Holiday holiday1 = new Holiday();
                    holiday1.PersonId = PersonId.Value;
                    holiday1.HolidayDate = startDates;

                    db.Holidays.AddObject(holiday1);
                    db.SaveChanges();



                    //say start date is 10. AddDays(1) will make it 11 then return it to startDates in 'startDates' = startdates,
                    //but doesnt chage the value of startdates = 'startdates'
                }

                startDates = startDates.AddDays(1);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

if holidayDate = db.exisitng date?

Unsure how to go about this.

Please advise.

Comment: I don't know how you would link them together, but seems like a perfect case for a custom data annotation validation attribute.

Comment: what? sorry still a bit of a intermediate at this...any advise?

Comment: Check out this as an example: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/21/custom-data-annotation-validator-part-i-server-code.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are needing to do, you have a few options open to you:

1. Pre-load the existing dates into some type of JS array/collection and then do validation against that array when the value has been changed.
2. Attach an ajax query to the changed event of the datepicker.  When the user changes the date, do a query and validate that date.

   ```
        $('.date-pick').bind('dateSelected',function (e, selectedDate, $td){
       $.ajax({
          url:'somepath/action',
          data: {selectedDateVal: selectedDate},
          success:function(result){
               if(result == true){
                 //value exists
                }else{
                  //value is good
                }
          }
       });}); ​
   ```
3. Look into custom data annotations.  Wish I could provide more input on this, but unfortunately I haven't had a great deal of experience in this area.